# Android Glide doesn't get the newest version of the picture

Tags: android, firebase, caching, firebase-storage, android-glide

Trying to work with Glide for Android and Firebase.

My code is working perfectly (uploading, downloading into ImageViews), my problem is that when I change the image in the Firebase Storage (for example, a user image), the app doesn't "know" that the image in the database has changed and keeps showing the cached version.

Obviously I want the app to use cache, but in a way that knows if the original image has changed in the database.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: do you replace the image of user when you "change" image or do you simply add a new image? In case of later, do you update the path of new image in the database?

Comment: thanks, I'm replacing the image, not adding another image in another path.

Comment: if the URL is not changing, then I am not sure if there is anyway for Glide to know that image has changed.

Comment: Somehow, can you know that user has updated his image? If you can then you can use `(new StringSignature(UUID.randomUUID().toString()))` to re-download the same image even if URL is not changed

Comment: If you want to have your app load the new image when there's been a change, you will need to implement a way to notify the app that the image has changed. The easiest way to do that is probably to simply upload a new image to storage and change the URL in wherever your app gets it from.

Answer (score 2):

if cache is not wanted, you can try

```
Glide.with(ctx)
    .load(Uri))
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
    .skipMemoryCache(true)
    .into(mImage);
```

And also This will remove cache memory which is stored by Glide.

```
Glide.get(ctx).clearDiskCache();
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to use the cache AND have glide "understand" that the image in the database has changed (in it's original path).

Comment: I do not know if it can be done with Firebase , but you can change the image while the url path is the same. With this way new image will be  download